# URLs pointing to wrong virtual directory on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, virtual-directory

I have an IIS web application called "WebApp" created inside the "Default Web Site". The WebApp has a virutal directory with a repository of images called "Repository".

```
Schema:
-Default Web Site
    -WebApp
        -Repository
```

When I execute the web application like this:

```
http://localhost/WebApp
```

All my images points to a relative url like `"/Repository/ImageDir/image.jpg`" which is interpreted like `http://localhost/Repository/ImageDir/image.jpg`.

That URL is wrong, because since my virtual directory is inside `WebApp`, the correct URL should be `http://localhost**/WebApp**/Repository/ImageDir/image.jpg`

How can I make it generate a correct URL.

Just for more info, the web application is in ASP.NET MVC.

**UPDATE:**

I'm using Razor in my views, so here is the code to generate a img tag:

```
<img src="@m.ThumbPath" />
```

Where "m" is an element of the Model (which is a List of elements) and "ThumbPath" contains the relative path that is giving problems.

Comment: Add your code, what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Asp.Net MVC you should be using [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx)-helper to generate the url to resources inside your app:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~{0}", m.ThumbPath))">
```

Comment: This answer is still valid.